# How to decode which version of Golang to install on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, go, osx-yosemite

On the official Golang website, in the [Get Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) section, we read:

> **Install the Go tools**
>
> If you are upgrading from an older version of Go you must first remove
>   the existing version.
>
> Linux, Mac OS X, and FreeBSD tarballs
>
> Download the archive and extract it into /usr/local, creating a Go
>   tree in `/usr/local/go`. For example:
>
> `tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz`
>
> Choose the archive
>   file appropriate for your installation. For instance, if you are
>   installing Go version 1.2.1 for 64-bit x86 on Linux, the archive you
>   want is called go1.2.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz.
>
> (Typically these commands must be run as root or through sudo.)
>
> Add `/usr/local/go/bin` to the PATH environment variable. You can do
>   this by adding this line to your `/etc/profile` (for a system-wide
>   installation) or `$HOME/.profile`:
>
> `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

When we visit the [Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/) section, we are presented with many options:

> go1.4.2
>
> **File name  Kind    OS  Arch    SHA1 Checksum**
>
> go1.4.2.src.tar.gz    Source          460caac03379f746c473814a65223397e9c9a2f6
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-386-osx10.6.tar.gz Archive OS X
>   10.6+ 32-bit  fb3e6b30f4e1b1be47bbb98d79dd53da8dec24ec
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-386-osx10.8.tar.gz Archive OS X
>   10.8+ 32-bit  65f5610fdb38febd869aeffbd426c83b650bb408
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-386-osx10.6.pkg    Installer   OS X
>   10.6+ 32-bit  3ed569ce33616d5d36f963e5d7cefb55727c8621
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-386-osx10.8.pkg    Installer   OS X
>   10.8+ 32-bit  7f3fb2438fa0212febef13749d8d144934bb1c80
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-amd64-osx10.6.tar.gz   Archive OS X
>   10.6+ 64-bit  00c3f9a03daff818b2132ac31d57f054925c60e7
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-amd64-osx10.8.tar.gz   Archive OS X
>   10.8+ 64-bit  58a04b3eb9853c75319d9076df6f3ac8b7430f7f
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-amd64-osx10.6.pkg  Installer   OS X
>   10.6+ 64-bit  3fa5455e211a70c0a920abd53cb3093269c5149c
>
> go1.4.2.darwin-amd64-osx10.8.pkg  Installer   OS X
>   10.8+ 64-bit  8fde619d48864cb1c77ddc2a1aec0b7b20406b38

I run **Mac OS X Yosemite, Version 10.10.3**, with the following configuration:

- **Processor**: 2.8 GHz Intel Core i5
- **Memory**: 8 Go 1600 MHz DDR3
- **Graphics**: Intel Iris 1536 Mo

Which version of Go should I install?

And most importantly, why (so that I can make a decision for myself in the future)?

Comment: for ease of management HomeBrew (http://brew.sh/) has a version og Go packaged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want this one:

> go1.4.2.darwin-amd64-osx10.8.pkg Installer OS X 10.8+ 64-bit

Note the key parts: amd64 (64-bit), OS X 10.8+ (of which 10.10.3 satisfies). It's the GUI installer, which automates a lot of the work.

Mac OS X is often referred to as "darwin", which is the name for the low-level OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.